# Means and Variances

Tags: statistics

For a laboratory assignment, if the equipment is
working, the density function of the observed outcome
$X$ is

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 2(1-x), & 0 <x<1, \\
0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$

Find the variance and standard deviation of $X$.

We know that the variance is related to the mean and the second moment. I am stuck on how to set up the integrals for the both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrals are
$$
\text{mean} = \mu = \int_0^1 x f(x) \, dx
$$
and
$$
\text{variance} = \sigma^2 = \int_0^1 (x-\mu)^2 f(x)\,dx.
$$
In order to evaluate the second integral, one must find $\mu$ by evaluating the first integral.

The second integral is the variance $\sigma^2$; the standard deviation is the square root of that.

Answer (score 3):

The mean is given by
$$E(X)=\int_0^1 (x)(2(1-x))\,dx.$$
For the calculation, note that $(x)(2(1-x))=2x-2x^2$.

For the variance, if $\mu$ is the mean, then
$$\text{Var}(X)=E((X-\mu)^2)=\int_0^1 (x-\mu)^2(2(1-x))\,dx.$$

It is often the case that this is not the most convenient way to evaluate the variance. An often more useful formula is
$$\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2.$$

To find $E(X^2)$, we use
$$E(X^2)=\int_0^1 (x^2)(2(1-x))\,dx.$$